# Change the timezone from UTC to GMT+1 in MS CRM On Premise Database

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is there any way to change the timezone from UTC to GMT+1 in the CRM database.
We have onpremise CRM. The issue we are facing like we have more than 100 reports running directly at crm database.
To convert all the dates to from UTC to GMT+1 will be time consuming and difficult. Also converting all the data time fields to date only is not possible.

As all the users belongs to a single timezone. Can we convert from UTC to GMT+1 in the database it self.
If we can convert what will be impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot simply change that, as CRM product is designed to store all the datetime stamps as UTC in database. This actually helps to work/consume/transact by CRM users in multiple timezone without issues.

You should better prepare a wrapper function to convert to local timezone and use the stored values when reading or simply train the user to see it as it is, ie UTC

Comment: Thank you for time https://stackoverflow.com/users/7920473/arun-vinoth